# How to optimize a list all mongoose query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

In the last few days I was busy trying to improve & optimize as mush as I can the mongoose queries for a website.
The main thing I found for that was to use indexes which I've already done.
But there's a problem...
In my mongo schemas I have few "list all" queries , what I mean by that is :
A query that will return everything from that model and it doesn't have any parameter .

I'm currently working on NodeJS v8.15.1 with ExpressJS and MongoDB v4.0.6

The kind of query I'm talking about , and the example below is one of my actually queries :

```
ModelSchema.statics.listAll = function ( callback ){
 try {
  return  this.find( {}, callback ).select({"x":0,"y":0});
 } catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  return null;
 }
};
```

As you can see , I'm trying to get everything from that model excepting the x & y fields.

The query is perfectly working , there isn't any problem.
As long as it doesn't use any indexed field it won't run faster or anything like that.
But I wonder if there is a way to optimize it ?

Thank you very much for help!

Comment: There isn't any way to optimize this query. Even though you somehow managed to use an indexed field to query and return all documents, this would still take similar execution time unless you filter the results to reduce returned documents.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found an answer :
I could fix that problem by caching the request and query for it again everytime it changes.